# Очень большой размер приложения iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Я использую в своем приложении

- карты Гугла,
- камеру,
- базу данных sqlite,
- управление жестами,

и с учетом того, что в приложении пока нет никаких картинок или других больших ресурсов (база данных весит всего 1,4 Мб), после сборки вес приложения получается 1,5 Гб.

Как можно его уменьшить? Это из-за того что я подключаю очень много библиотек или из-за чего-то другого?

Comment: скорее всего Вы просто собрали в отладочном режиме приложение.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос закрыт, простой Clean помог. Теперь 16 Мб весит. Всем спасибо!